# Can Java 5 be installed on any other OS other than OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, mac, java

I have a legacy application that requires Java 5. I am using OS X 10.6.8. When I try to install the Apple Java 1.5 update, I see a warning that says Java 5 can only be installed on a OS X 10.5 system. Is this the only OS X version that supports Java 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100123192950640) indicates one might use the shareware package [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/), to unpack and then reuse old Apple installers for Java 5 on Snow Leopard.

Disclaimer: The original author of this comment has no known affiliation or vested interest with the software vendor for Pacifist, nor has actually tried this himself. Still, there seem to be a lot of happy users in the linked thread. :)